# How to get the Customer id of each by json data returned from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have JSON data like this :

```
[
  {
    "CustomerID": "100",
    "ContactName": "Indocin",
    "City": "David"
  },
  {
    "CustomerID": "200",
    "ContactName": "Enebrel",
    "City": "Sam"
  },
  {
    "CustomerID": "300",
    "ContactName": "Hydralazine",
    "City": "Dhaka"
  }
]
```

How I can get the Customer id of each by json data returned from server?

Comment: how you access this data? by calling the Server via AJAX? or your controller perhaps? please elaborate.

Comment: I have called the WebMethod (c#) and the webmethod returns the json data

Comment: so, you access the data using AJAX then? if so, please post your javascript code to call your server.

Comment: @Belayet you need to get the CustomerID client side right? if so just call JSON.parse(string) to get a regular js object. do yourself a favor and correct the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
function func() {
        var JsonData = [
      {
          "CustomerID": "100",
          "ContactName": "Indocin",
          "City": "David"
      },
      {
          "CustomerID": "200",
          "ContactName": "Enebrel",
          "City": "Sam"
      },
      {
          "CustomerID": "300",
          "ContactName": "Hydralazine",
          "City": "Dhaka"
      }
    ];
       GetCustomerID(JsonData);
    }
    function GetCustomerID(JsonData) {
        alert(JsonData);
        var custIDArray = new Array(JsonData.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < JsonData.length; i++) {
            custIDArray[i] = JsonData[i]["CustomerID"];        
        }
        return custIDArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the library [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to deserialize the JSON into an object. You can install the library over [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

First you need to create a model for your JSON:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize this and iterate over all your customers to get the info:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);
foreach (var customer in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} with ID {1} and City {2}", customer.ContactName, customer.CustomerID, customer.City);
}
```